# How to play the video from SD card in webview using Iframe in Android?

Tags: android, iframe, video

I am using webview to play youtube videos. This is working fine. But I wanted to try this. How can I play the video from SD card in Webview using Iframe in android.

Any other possibilities are there to do this? Can I try any HTML5 video tag? Anyone can suggest me about this?

If I installed Flash Player of my device and enable such browser plugins then could I be able to play local videos from SD card inside webview?

Comment: Given that the question seems to be "shall I try an HTML video tag", and the accepted solution is "try an HTML5 video tag", I think this question can be marked as unclear or too broad. I am not sure exactly what help has been exchanged here, to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add custom HTML code to display in the webview and using HTML5 video tag you can acheive this task. Give it some try.

Comment: I dont want video tag, needed only Iframe tag !

Comment: That is also a part of HTML so you can customize the HTML code and set it display in Webview